# Cross entropy loss is not twice differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, machine-learning

Pardon if this seems off topic, I was reading this recent theory paper in machine learning by Kenji Kawaguchi and Leslie Pack Kaelbling

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.00279.pdf

and the authors seem to suggest in section 2.2 that cross-entropy loss for classification is not twice differentiable. This seems wrong, I thought it was $C^\infty$.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.00279.pdf) correctly, I think the problem was with **PA2**, not with the $C^2$ requirement. Although one does have problems at zero, which they may have also meant. The **PA2** requirement requires that the loss can be written $L(f,y) = \ell(-yf)$, which doesn't seem doable for the CE loss.

Comment: If that's what they meant, it's definitely not clearly written as binary cross-entropy can be written as "l(-yf)" and therefore does satisfy PA2:  "These assumptions prevent us from applying these results to multiclass classification, regression, or even binary classification with standard loss criteria (e.g., cross entropy loss and differentiable, yet not twice differentiable, smoothed hinge loss)."